# Equation arrangement.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

How to arrange $x=\frac{1}{2} \ln({1+\frac{10}{x}})$ to $x=\frac{10}{e^{2x}-1}$ ?

Can anyone give me step by step explanation? Thanks in advance.

Comment: (1) multiply both sides by 2; (2) exp both sides; (3) subtract 1 from both sides; (4) invert both sides; (5) multiply both sides by 10.

Comment: Are you sure both of the variables are meant to be $x$?

Comment: $x=\ln(\sqrt{1+\frac{10}{x}})$; $e^x= \sqrt{1+\frac{10}{x}}$; $e^{2x}=1+\frac{10}{x}$;...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$x=\frac{1}{2} \ln({1+\frac{10}{x}})$$

Begin by multiplying by $2$ on both sides.

$$2x= \ln({1+\frac{10}{x}})$$

Now, exponentiate by $e$ on both sides.

$$e^{2x}= {1+\frac{10}{x}}$$

Next, subtract $1$ from both sides.

$$e^{2x}-1= \frac{10}{x}$$

Finally, invert the equation (take both sides to a power of $-1$).

$$\frac{1}{e^{2x}-1}= \frac{x}{10}$$

Finally, multiply by $10$.

$$\frac{10}{e^{2x}-1}= x$$

Answer (score 0):

$x=\frac{1}{2} \ln(1+ \frac{10}{x}) \implies 2x= \ln(1+ \frac{10}{x}) \implies
e^{2x} = 1+ \frac{10}{x} \implies e^{2x} - 1 =\frac{10}{x} \implies x= \frac{10}{ e^{2x} - 1}
$